# Is it possible to render/view html using gomobile?

Tags: ios, go, webview, wkwebview, gomobile

Is it possible to render html pages using gomobile? I would like to spawn a http server which serves html/css in a separate go runtine and then render it in a webview. There are plenty of options for JavaScript applications(i.e. PhoneGap, ReactNative etc) so I'm wondering why there is close to none for Go.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the works to create a webview component; https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10247 but is not functional yet (although the recent discussion on the desktop webview may help things along).

Just to clarify; ReactNative does not embed a webview, it uses JSX to render native components.